# How to set validation as optional in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I want to make roles to be available only for admin can select roles for users and while user wants to edit the profile information can only see his roles but can't edit his role how to make it roles field to be locked for users 
Following code :

```
<div class="form-group"> 
{{ Form::label('role', 'Roles', array('class' => 'control-label mb-1')) }} <br/> 
{{ Form::select('roles[]',$roles,$selectedRoles,['class'=>'myselect','data-placeholder'=>'Select role(s)', 'multiple'] ) }} 
</div>
```

Comment: Please include details on how that isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
//..

if(!$request->filled('roles')) {
   $request->merge(['roles' => []]);
}

$this->validate($request,[
    'name' => 'required',
    'email' => 'required|email', //'required|email|unique:users,email',
    'password' => [ 'string', 'min:8'],
    'roles' => 'nullable|array', 
    'roles.*' => [Rule::requiredIf($request->filled('roles')), 'exists:roles,id'],  
],[
    'name.required' => "Name field is required",
    'email.required' => "Email Field is Required",

    'email.email' => "Invalid Email Format ",

    'password.min' => "The Password Must be at Least 8 Characters or More",
    'roles.*' => "The Role is Required",
]);

//...
```

Comment: it still gives me same error " Invalid argument supplied for foreach() "

Comment: thank you it works , but i want to make roles to be available only for admin can select roles for users and while user wants to edit the profile information can see his roles but can't edit his role how to make it locked for users  Following code : <div class="form-group">
            {{ Form::label('role', 'Roles', array('class' => 'control-label mb-1')) }}
                                    <br/>
            {{ Form::select('roles[]',$roles,$selectedRoles,['class'=>'myselect','data-placeholder'=>'Select role(s)', 'multiple'] )  }}
                                </div>

Comment: Glad to help, could you please edit the original post, so it can be much more readable